how can I fix that. dyld[94690]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libOgreMain.1.9.0.dylib
after installing gazebo, I try running gazebo.
but face this problem.
dyld[94690]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libOgreMain.1.9.0.dylib
Referenced from: <7D01D4C4-8CAF-33D4-97A0-57B845E5A9A0> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ogre1.9/1.9-20160714-108ab0bcc69603dba32c0ffd4bbbc39051f421c9_10/lib/libOgreRTShaderSystem.1.9.0.dylib
Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gazebo11/11.14.0_19/lib/../lib/libOgreMain.1.9.0.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gazebo11/11.14.0_19/lib/../lib/libOgreMain.1.9.0.dylib' '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gazebo11/11.14.0_19/lib/../lib/libOgreMain.1.9.0.dylib'in.1.9.0.dylib' (no such file)Library not loaded: @rpath/libOgrePaging.1.9.0.dylib
how can I fix that????
on Mac OS m3
I don't know that solve that

I tried setting the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to point to the directory containing the Ogre libraries before launching Gazebo.
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ogre1.9/1.9-20160714-108ab0bcc69603dba32c0ffd4bbbc39051f421c9_10/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

After doing this gazebo should run fine.
